# C++ header implementation check

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, header-files

Is there any way you can force the C++ compiler to do a symbol check on all your header files?  I'd like to know what's missing in my library without referencing everything...

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that, just visual studio 2010.

Comment: What do you mean by "symbol check"?

Comment: You know, just to see if all the implementations are there that are defined in the header